# Convert epoch time to standard datetime from json python?

Tags: python, json, datetime, epoch

I have a JSON:

```
[{'id':'1',
'name':'rob',
'created':'1577431544986' 
    },

{'id':'2',
'name':'tom',
'created':'1566431234567' 
    }]
```

I need to convert the UNIX timestamp present in the JSON to standard DateTime.

My final output should be:

```
[{'id':'1',
'name':'rob',
'created':'27-12-2019' 
    },

{'id':'2',
'name':'tom',
'created':'22-08-2019' 
    }]
```

What i have done:

I'm able to figure out doing it for single variable:

```
import datetime
time = '1566431234567'
your_dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time)/1000)
print(your_dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))


'22-08-2019'
```

But how to use the same in above JSON?

Comment: Do you have the JSON loaded as a dictionary? Just access the field, perform your conversion and update the field

Answer (score 2):

Epoch time is the number of seconds passed since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 and you can convert it to human date time as

```
import time
# seconds passed since epoch
seconds = 1545925769.9618232
local_time = time.ctime(seconds)
print("Local time:", local_time)
```

For more details check https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html

Comment: How to add the same in JSON

Comment: read the json file with json library convert it to dictionary and with key 'created' change  the value and save it